# SSL using x.509 certificates cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ssl, x509

I wanted to know where exactly in xcode do I place a x.509 certificate that I have. Taking the example from here:
http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/downloads/detail?name=CertTest.zip&can=1&q=

I wanted to be able to communicate with a secure server I have running. I just cant seem to add the certificate in and everytime I do, my mac opens up a keychain window asking m if the certificate belongs to any of my system (other than my project) settings. So I wanted to know where do I place it in my project and how I would use it(I guess the project at the link would help with that)

Comment: Do you want to us certificate to authenticate on server?

Comment: yes thats right. i cant seem to get the authentication done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NSURLConnection for connecting to your server then you should implement next methods in your delegate:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace;
// A delegate method called by the NSURLConnection when something happens with the 
// connection security-wise.  We defer all of the logic for how to handle this to 
// the ChallengeHandler module (and it's very custom subclasses).


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
// A delegate method called by the NSURLConnection when you accept a specific 
// authentication challenge by returning YES from -connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:. 
// Again, most of the logic has been shuffled off to the ChallengeHandler module; the only 
// policy decision we make here is that, if the challenge handle doesn't get it right in 5 tries, 
// we bail out.
```

I advice you to look through this sample by Apple: [Advanced Url Connections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: ah yes. that should work. thanks! didnt know about that example.